# Need to understand the syntax class Builder<T extends Builder<T>>

Tags: java, generics

I am following examples in "Effective Java" and came across the following code:

```
abstract static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>>
```

and its implementation:

```
public static class Builder extends Pizza.Builder<Builder>
```

Why is this declared `T extends Builder<T>` and not `T extends Builder`. Is it really needed to add the template `<T>`? What is the impact if I just use `Builder<T extends Builder>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called as "generic type". That declaration means `T` can be any type that is subclass of `Builder<T>`.

The goal of implementing *Generics* is finding bugs in compile-time other than in run-time. Finding bugs in compile-time can save time for debugging java program, because compile-time bugs are much easier to find and fix.

> What is the impact if we just use `Builder<T extends Builder>`?

It transforms into *[raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)*. And type safety goes off.

`Builder<T extends Builder<T>>` means that,

The class `T` passed in must implement the `Builder` interface / extend `Builder` class, and the generic parameter of `Builder` must be `T` itself.

Answer (score 3):

I have some examples to show that actually the difference is not that big. I think the OP wants to know the difference between `T extends Builder<T>` and `T extends Builder`.

```
public abstract class Builder2<T extends Builder2> {
//doesn't compile either, because String is not a subtype of Builder2
static class WrongHouseBuilder extends Builder2<String> {}
//all ok
static class RawHouseBuilder extends Builder2 {}
static class HouseBuilder1 extends Builder2<RawHouseBuilder> {}
static class HouseBuilder2 extends Builder2<HouseBuilder1> {}
static class HouseBuilder3 extends Builder2<HouseBuilder2> {}}
```

Now with `Builder<T>`:

```
public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {
//all ok
static class RawCarBuilder extends Builder {}
static class CarBuilder extends Builder<CarBuilder> {}
//ok as well, T doesn't have to be CarBuilder2
static class CarBuilder2 extends Builder<CarBuilder> {}
//doesn't compile because CarBuilder2 is not a subtype of Builder<CarBuilder2>
static class CarBuilder3 extends Builder<CarBuilder2> {}}
```

Of cause with `T extends Builder<T>`, you have more protection, but not that much.

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify, we should not use raw type. @Radiodef has provided an interesting example in the comment. And a quote from that answer to help you understand it:

> In simpler terms, when a raw type is used, the constructors, instance methods and non-static fields are also erased.

Comment: Using a raw type in the bound has more drastic consequences than just what you can supply as a type argument. Using a raw type erases all the members of `T`, so [stuff like this compiles](https://ideone.com/xCeii8). Also see [*What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2891664).

Comment: @Radiodef thank you for the comment, I didn't know it. When I say not that much, I mean the examples in other answers and `CarBuilder2 `, I was expecting it to be self bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Minor: It looks more natural to me to use `Builder` as an `interface`, not an `abstract class`. This is a sort of recursive type declaration. It is used for type safety to prevent nasty things like the following happens:

```
public abstract Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {
    T build();
}


public class Entity extends Builder<String>{ // does not compile
    @Override
    public String build() {
        return null;
    }
}


public class Entity extends Builder<Entity>{ //ok
    @Override
    public Entity build() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Anyway more naturally looking version (from my point of view) is:

```
public interface Buildable<T extends Buildable<T>> {
    T build();
}

public final class Entity implements Buildable<Entity>{
    //other methods
    @Override
    public Entity build() {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Method `T build()` with `T extends Builder<T>` makes no sense.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski please, expand.

Comment: `T extends Builder<T>` can only return itself. So your `build` method, instead of returning something other to be built, can only return an instance of the same class. What else than `Entity.this` would your `Entity.build()` method return? Your `Entity` should not be named `Entity` - it should be named `EntityBuilder`, and its `build()` method should return an `Entity`. Right now, your `Entity` class tries to be two things at once (a builder and an entity), violating the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski Have to agree it makes a little sense.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the question is about the `<T>` part in `Builder<T>`. Without this `<T>`, you simply get a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), and your IDE might complain.

But in my answer, I'd like to explain what's the purpose of `T extends Builder<T>`, because other answers do not seem to cover it (maybe you know this already).

`T extends Builder<T>` serves the purpose of returning appropriate `Builder.this` in all the `Builder` methods (except `build()` method, of course).

I usually use it with a protected abstract method like `T thisInstance()`.

Example:

```
abstract class NamedBuilder<T extends NamedBuilder<T>> {
    private String name;

    T name(String name) {
         this.name = name;
         return thisInstance();
    }

    protected abstract T thisInstance();
}

final class MoreSpecificBuilder extends NamedBuilder<MoreSpecificBuilder> {
     @Override
     protected MoreSpecificBuilder thisInstance() {
         return this;
     }
}
```

Thanks to such approach, you do not have to redefine `name()` method in all the `NamedBuilder` subclasses to return the specific subclass.

Without <del>such constraint</del> *type parameter `T`*, you would have:

```
 abstract class NamedBuilder {
     NamedBuilder name(String name);
 }
```

and you would need to override all such methods in subclasses like that:

```
final class MoreSpecificBuilder extends NamedBuilder {
     @Override
     MoreSpecificBuilder name(String name) {
         super.name(name);
         return this;
     }
}
```

*EDIT*: Without the *constraint* `extends Builder<T>` on type parameter `T`:

```
abstract class NamedBuilder<T> {
  // ...
}
```

this would work fine, *although* such design would be less intuitive and more error-prone.

Without such constraint, compiler would accept anything as `T` (e.g. `String`), so the constraint acts simply as a compile-time check for the implementors of `NamedBuilder`.

Comment: "Without such constraint, you would have:" No. Without the constraint, you would have `abstract class NamedBuilder<T> {`, and your first example without the constraint would still compile fine, so it doesn't explain why you have the constraint

Comment: @newacct Good point. I confused terminology - I confused *constraint* on type parameter with a *type parameter* itself. So: 1) without the *type parameter* you'd get the behavior I described, and 2) without the *constraint* on this type parameter, `T` could represent *anything*, so you have the constraint just to make sure that `T` indeed represents `NamedBuilder`.